# Filter NSMutableDictionary data in UITableView

Tags: ios, uitableview, filter, uisearchbar, nsmutabledictionary

I need to filter data in `UITableview` by text entered in `UISearchbar`. I followed [this example](http://code-ninja.org/blog/2012/01/08/ios-quick-tip-filtering-a-uitableview-with-a-search-bar/) but there data in `NSMutableArray` and I can't alter it under my requirements. My data is `NSMutableDictionary`. I'm stuck on this for long time.

My data:

```
NSArray *documentPaths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSCachesDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *path = [[documentPaths lastObject] stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"data.plist"];
NSDictionary *dict = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithContentsOfFile:path];

NSMutableDictionary *resultDic = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
NSMutableArray *resultArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
NSDictionary *myDict = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithContentsOfFile:path];

sectionKeys = [NSMutableArray new];
sectionsTitle = [NSMutableArray new];

NSArray *tableArray = [myDict objectForKey:@"Black"];
[resultArray addObject:@"Black"];
[resultDic setValue:tableArray forKey:@"Black"];
[sectionsTitle addObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", [tableData valueForKey:@"Black"]]];
[sectionCord addObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", [tableData valueForKey:@"Coordinates"]]];
[sectionKeys addObject:@"Section1"];

self.tableData = resultDic;
self.sectionsTitle = resultArray;

[myTable reloadData];
```

My table:

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {
    return sectionKeys.count;
}


- (NSString *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView titleForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    return [sectionKeys objectAtIndex:section];
}


- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    int rowCount;
    if(self.isFiltered)
        rowCount = [[filteredTableData objectForKey:[sectionsTitle objectAtIndex:section]] count];

    else
        rowCount = [[tableData objectForKey:[sectionsTitle objectAtIndex:section]] count];

    return rowCount;
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil)
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];


    if(isFiltered){
         NSDictionary *dict = [[filteredTableData objectForKey:[sectionsTitle objectAtIndex:indexPath.section]] objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

        cell.textLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", [dict objectForKey:@"Name"]];
        cell.detailTextLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", [dict objectForKey:@"Address"]];
    }
    else{
         NSDictionary *dict = [[tableData objectForKey:[sectionsTitle objectAtIndex:indexPath.section]] objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

        cell.textLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", [dict objectForKey:@"Name"]];
        cell.detailTextLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", [dict objectForKey:@"Address"]];
    }


    return cell;
}
```

My search:

```
#pragma mark - SearchBar Delegate -
-(void)searchBar:(UISearchBar *)searchBar textDidChange:(NSString *)text{


    if(text.length == 0)
    {
        isFiltered = FALSE;
        NSLog(@"false");
    }
    else
    {
        isFiltered = true;
        NSLog(@"true");
        filteredTableData = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];

        for (MyAnnotation* ann in tableData)
        {
            NSRange nameRange = [ann.title rangeOfString:text options:NSCaseInsensitiveSearch];
            NSRange descriptionRange = [ann.description rangeOfString:text options:NSCaseInsensitiveSearch];
            if(nameRange.location != NSNotFound || descriptionRange.location != NSNotFound)
            {
                [filteredTableData addObject:ann];
                //error
            }
        }
    }

    [myTable reloadData];

}
```

Comment: Can you show your "data.plist"?

Comment: I added a plist construction to the question

Comment: The way you form your data is very confusing. There is no need to keep this many different arrays. You only need to have a two arrays. One will be containing all the values and the other one will be the dataSource to the tableView. Based on your "filter keywords" you filter the data from main array and assign to dataSource. Reload the tableView for dataSource change. You can make use of NSPredicate for filtering. I can't make out a correct way to filter based on your given data. I can helf if you can provide some real data.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you need to create a state/flag for the controller/data source, in order for it to know weather you are in search/filter mode.

Then, if you are in search mode, point the data source methods to the filteredArray.

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {
    int numberOfSections = 0;
    if (_searchMode)
        {
              numberOfSections = self.filteredDataDict.allKeys.count;
        }
        else
        {
              numberOfSections = self.tableData.allKeys.count;
        }
    return numberOfSections;

}
```

Hope it's understood.