# How to put the data in the right section in UITableViewController?

Tags: uitableview, swift, parse-platform, tableview

So I have created multiple objects in parse and I want to put them in different section in UITableView based on their creation date ("createdAt" object). I have tried a lot but couldn't find any answer. 
For example, If today is March 25th, all the objects that are created today will be in the section called March 25th. (preferably in swift)
I'll appreciate any help.

Answer (score 0):

Okay. First of all, this question isn't well written. Reffer to the SO guide on how to write good questions that appears when you create one. This can reduce the chance of getting your account block, and your threads closed. Have you tried anything specifically to solve your problem as yet? If so, what have you tried? This info could help other developers.

I'd reccomend that you write a basic PFQuery to retrieve all of the data. After the query you can save the data into an NSMutableDictionary or an NSArray (their are tutorials on SO and Parse.com documentation) so you would reduce the number of requests coming into the database which would help you save money on Parse.com.

After you have this in an NSMutableDictionary you can put it into the table view and ask the user to click the button to filter data created today. When this button is clicked, it could start the NSMutableDictionary filteration could which could be something like this:

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {
    int numberSections = 0;
    if (_searchMode)
        {
              numberSections = self.filteredDataDict.allKeys.count;
        }
        else
        {
              numberSections = self.tableData.allKeys.count;
        }
    return numberSections;

}
```

*Originally shown as an example by @Avi Tsadok on SO forums.*
To read more about filtering Mutable Dictionaries click [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16130926/filter-nsmutabledictionary-data-in-uitableview/).

I hope my logic has helped you,
armanb21

### If you have any questions just tag me in the comments.

If my answer has helped you please hit the up arrow button on the left of my post.

Comment: Thanks @armanb21 seems i cannot vote yet , but when i receive enough reputations, i'll come back and vote for you